# Calling a pointer method on a struct in a map

Tags: pointers, methods, dictionary, struct, go

There is the type Company, which is a struct, containing a map of Person's, which are also all structs.

```
type Company struct {
    employees map[int]Person
}

type Person struct {
    [...]
}
```

After allocating some Person's to the employees-map, I'm trying to call a pointer method on each of these.

```
func (company *Company) Populate(names []string) {
    for i := 1; i <= 15; i++ {
        company.employees[i] = Person{names[i - 1], [...]}
        company.employees[i].Initialize()
    }
}
```

This miserably fails, with the go-Compiler complaining that I can't call pointer methods on *company.employees[i]*, as well as I can't take the address of *company.employees[i]*.
However, setting the Initialize-method to a **non-pointer method** and letting it **return the copy of the person**, and allocating it to the map again by using

```
company.employees[i] = company.employees[i].Initialize()
```

works, which is not that different.

Not having worked with pointers ever this bugs me quite much. Map's aren't immutable, and they get modified either way, so calling a pointer method on an entity in a map shouldn't be a problem - atleast in my head.

If anyone could explain to me what I'm doing wrong here - or correct my thinking - I'd be pleased.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem here is that in order to call a pointer method, the address of `employees[i]` needs to be taken. According to the [Go specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators):

> The operand must be addressable, that is, either a variable, pointer indirection, or slice indexing operation; or a field selector of an addressable struct operand; or an array indexing operation of an addressable array. As an exception to the addressability requirement, x may also be a composite literal.

A map indexing operation is not addressable. This was decided so that map implementations would not need to guarantee that the addresses of values would not change. As more data is added to the map, it may relocate data for efficiency reasons.

So, how can you fix it? If you have a `map[int]*Person`, you will not need to take the address of the data in the map since the map value is already an address.

One last bit of advice, `Person.Initialize()` is not very idiomatic Go code. If you need to initialize a type, you normally use a `NewPerson()` function. The `NewPerson()` function would return an initialized Person struct or pointer.

Comment: Thank you very much for making this clear. I've followed both your hints and removed the Initialize-method (though that was just a temporary name anyway) and created a NewPerson() function containing that bit of code and returning an initialized person. Using a map adressing Person-pointers resulted in less and - together with NewPerson() - better understandable code.

Answer (score 1):

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Person struct {
    Name string
}

func NewPerson(name string) *Person {
    return &Person{Name: name}
}

type Company struct {
    Employees map[int]*Person
}

func (c *Company) Populate(names []string) {
    c.Employees = make(map[int]*Person)
    for i := range names {
        c.Employees[i+1] = NewPerson(names[i])
    }
}

func main() {
    c := Company{}
    c.Populate([]string{"Peter", "Paul"})
    for k, v := range c.Employees {
        fmt.Println(k, *v)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1 {Peter}
2 {Paul}
```